# ASP.NET Web Api with OWIN - Custom authentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api2, owin, api-key

I'm trying to create a new API Key custom authentication provider to plug into my OWIN pipeline.
I'm using Cookie, OAuth and ADFS providers as well.
The code I've implemented is pretty much this:

```
public static class ApiKeyAuthenticationExtension
{
    public static IAppBuilder UseApiKeyAuthentication(this IAppBuilder appBuilder, ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions options = null)
    {
        appBuilder.Use<ApiKeyAuthenticationMiddleware>(options ?? new ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions("ApiKey"));
        appBuilder.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);

        return appBuilder;
    }
}

public class ApiKeyAuthenticationMiddleware : AuthenticationMiddleware<AuthenticationOptions>
{
    public ApiKeyAuthenticationMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next, AuthenticationOptions options) : base(next, options)
    {
    }

    protected override AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationOptions> CreateHandler()
    {
        return new ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler();
    }
}

public class ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationOptions>
{
    private const string ApiKey = ".....";

    protected override Task<AuthenticationTicket> AuthenticateCoreAsync()
    {
        string apiKey = Context.Request.Headers["ApiKey"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiKey) && ApiKey.Equals(apiKey))
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "Id", null, Options.AuthenticationType));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Name"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "bla@blu.com"));

            return new Task<AuthenticationTicket>(() => new AuthenticationTicket(identity, new AuthenticationProperties()));
        }

        return Task.FromResult(null as AuthenticationTicket);
    }
}

public class ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationOptions
{
    public ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions(string authenticationType) : base(authenticationType)
    {
    }
}
```

My Startup.Auth looks like this:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(...
app.UseActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthentication(...
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(...
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(...
```

and at the end

```
app.UseApiKeyAuthentication(...
```

When the execution goes into AuthenticateCoreAsync and I return and authentication ticket, the browser just hangs and execution seems to go nowhere. nothing happens after that.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the task you created is never finishing or even starting.
You might want to use Task.FromResult there as well or just change it to an async method.

```
    protected override Task<AuthenticationTicket> AuthenticateCoreAsync()
{
    string apiKey = Context.Request.Headers["ApiKey"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiKey) && ApiKey.Equals(apiKey))
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "Id", null, Options.AuthenticationType));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Name"));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "bla@blu.com"));

        return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationTicket(identity, new AuthenticationProperties()));
    }

    return Task.FromResult(null as AuthenticationTicket);
}
```